Try to name Worksheet from cell value in another sheet
Try to name Worksheet from cell value in another sheet.But not working...
Private Sub Worksheet_NameChange()

        ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets("Input").Range("P5").Value

End Sub

I want to name sheets that contain this private sub from sheets "Input" cells "P5".What should i do?

What is "not working"? Do you get an error? What's the value of your P5 cell?

How is your code called? Is it called at all?

No,i don't get an error. Just nothing happens when I change the value in P5 cell. The value in P5 is text "25 YRS."

Put the word Stop on a line by itself. That's how you can know if it's running it all. Maybe you are thinking there is an event called Worksheet_NameChange ? Where are you trying to call this routine from?

@FunThomas i don't understand your question.

A macro code must be somehow called. Either by the Macro-Menu (but your routine is private, so it's not listed there), by a call from other code, by an Event (but NameChange is not an Event), by a button or the like, or directly from the VBE (F5 or Immediate Window).

@braX I think it just the name of a private sub lol. So turns out Worksheet_NameChange is an event that I should change into an appropriate name?

Place the cursor on the word Private and press F5

@Blackcat how to automatic update, sir.

You need to use the event Worksheet_Change if you want it to update automatically and check if the Target and P5 intersect, if so, change the sheetname (see example here). (note: this won't be called if it's a formula in P5 showing a different value)

BeforeSave events are where I prefer to throw this type of naming convention, as it may change while people work.  If may behoove you to do the same, in case P5 changes regularly.

A Worksheet Activate: Rename Worksheet

Each time you activate (select) the sheet containing the following code, the code will attempt to rename the sheet using the value in cell Input!P5.

Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet2(Unknown)
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    With Me.Parent.Sheets("Input").Range("P5")
        If IsError(.Value) Then Exit Sub
        Dim NewName As String: NewName = .Value
        If NewName <> Me.Name Then Me.Name = NewName
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

A Worksheet Change: Rename Worksheet

The previous is a workaround to the impossible required behavior. IMO, a better solution would be to use the Worksheet Change event in the Input sheet when you would specify the sheet to be renamed using its code name. In VBE Project Explorer, the code name is the one not in parentheses i.e. CodeName(TabName).
In this case, the name will immediately change once you manually change the value in Input!P5 (if valid).
In the following code, replace both occurrences of Sheet2 with the actual code name of the sheet to be renamed.

Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1(Input)
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
             
    Dim tcell As Range: Set tcell = Intersect(Me.Range("P5"), Target)
    If tcell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With tcell 
        If IsError(.Value) Then Exit Sub
        Dim NewName As String: NewName = .Value
        If NewName <> Sheet2.Name Then Sheet2.Name = NewName
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

